# js chart dotnetcharting - how to remove background grids

Tags: asp.net, charts

Does anyone know how to remove background gridlines for a javascript chart with dotnetcharting?

(Chart.DefaultSeries.Type = SeriesType.Spline)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you were able to solve it or not but this is how you can do it.

Chart.YAxis.ShowGrid = False
Chart.XAxis.ShowGrid = False

Or

Chart.DefaultAxis.ShowGrid = False